# Robust RM ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, robust, mixed-type-data

I am an R beginner and I needed to run robust two way mixed ANOVAs with R using the WRS2 package and the function btwin because my data has nonnormal residuals (I looked at Q-Q plots) and there is a violation of homoscedasticity in some groups. In my data, I have a between the factor of two levels (treatment vs no treatment) and a withing factor (time) which has four levels (day 1, day 2, day 3, day 4).

My robust mixed ANOVA turned out significant for within and between effects but without significant interaction. Therefore, I wanted to do post hoc testing.

In the help function, there is a suggestion to use sppbb (within), sppba (between), and sppbi (interaction). After running those I obtain M-estimates of the comparisons and an overall p-value as you can see here.

```
sppbb(variable ~ BetweenFactor*WithinFactor, id=id, data=datlong)

Test statistics:
      Estimate
D1-D2  -0.4660
D1-D3   0.1827
D1-D4  -0.3589
D2-D3   0.7765
D2-D4   0.7064
D3-D4  -0.3212

Test whether the corresponding population parameters are the same:
p-value: 0.818
```

**EDIT**: For me it is not entirely clear the interpretation of this p value given the M-estimates. Could somebody help? If it was signifcant, how could I proceed?

Also, in the comments somebody said that using here a robust mixed ANOVA made no sense. Why is that?

Thank you

Comment: Please open the question, I don't see how it is not related to statistics when I am literally asking about robust mixed ANOVA. Also my question is not related to programming, I want to know how I should obtain the p values of each comparison. Thank you

Comment: I also don't see how this is off topic, unless the reviewer considered it to be too related to software. But I don't agree with that if it is the case. The question is perfectly related to statistics, imo.

Comment: Now, I dont know much about the subject matter. But do you know what is the distribution of the estimates under the null hypothesis? If you do, getting a p.value is easy.

Comment: "because my data has nonnormal residuals (I looked at Q-Q plots) and there is a violation of homoscedasticity in some groups." this doesn't really makes sense in terms of why you need a complicated robust mixed model anova

Comment: Short answer is no.. if you use this package there's no way of getting your comparions. And your question is closed because it is solely focused on how to use the package. If you edit your question to expand on your problem and how to address it, i can vote to reopen it

Comment: @StupidWolf why is doesn't make sense to use robust mixed ANOVA? I thought i could use it if the assumptions of mixed ANOVA were violated... What alternative would you suggest then?

Comment: @StupidWolf I also edited the question, I hope now it is fine

Comment: Asking for software recommendations (which is what your edit does) is still seen as off-topic here. Asking about the statistical issues underlying your problem would be on-topic.

Comment: @mdeway now it is just purely about stats I hope...